# sudo: syntax error after running ./stack.sh (devstack)

Tags: centos, openstack

The issue is coming while installing devstack for openstack.

Before running "./stack.sh" sudo was working fine, but after running this is happening:-

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/50_stack_sh: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/50_stack_sh: syntax error near line 2 <<<
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers.d/50_stack_sh: syntax error near line 3 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/50_stack_sh near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

and also the ./stack.sh stopped by saying :-

```
[ERROR] ./stack.sh:255 Error installing EPEL repo, cannot continue
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to do here

- cd /etc/sudoers.d
- vim<sup>*</sup> 50_stack_sh
- Examine line 1
- Examine line 2
- examine line 3

Now figure out what the problem is with the help of [this handy reference material](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html).

<sup><sup>*</sup></sup><sub>Other editors are available</sub>